# Power App form connected with Azure AD group not saving on submission to SP list

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp, azure-ad

So I have a Power App form that is connected with Azure AD group and pulls group members and populate my drop-down as a choice. Before this implementation the drop-down was searchable and it was populated from SharePoint Group.
The issue I’m having Now is, after switching from SharePoint group to azure A.D. group whenever I submit this form the drop-down field is not being saved into SharePoint list, previously it was saving in SharePoint list.
Is there some additional logic I need to add or I’m missing when switching to Azure A.D group to populate my drop down?
Please let me know if I need to add additional information to clarify this question.
Thanks

Comment: Just to clarify, are you trying to populate a person field in a sharepoint list with the user from an AAD group? My guess is that you need to convert the AAD user object into a SharePoint claim. Have a read of this post as it is pretty close to what I think you're trying to achieve: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Populating-people-picker-based-on-choice-field/td-p/199536

Comment: Thanks for the response, that is exactly what I need. I'll give it a try.